# Mirrored and alternating output strokes in CALayer context

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad

I am working on a Apple pencil app for my iPad and want to capture the pencil strokes in a sublayer.  Each time the pencil moves, I add a stroke to the sublayer and then save the image.  For the next stroke, I draw the saved image, add the next stroke, and save again.  For some reason, every other stroke gets mirrored opposite the previous stroke, so that it appears dashed images are displayed in mirror image across the horizontal center of the frame.  I know of other ways I can accomplish the same thing, but I really would like to know why this is happening - clearly something about use of Layers and CGContext I don't understand.  Below is the smallest set of code that re-creates the problem.  Note this is not my actual code (I use Views and Layers, etc) but I smashed everything into one VC to make it easy to re-create in a Single View Application:

```
import UIKit

var touch: UITouch!
var loc: CGPoint!
var prevLoc: CGPoint!

var lineWidth: CGFloat = 3
var drawColor: UIColor = UIColor.black

var myView: UIView!
var pLay: CALayer!
var img: CGImage!

class ViewController: UIViewController, CALayerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myView = self.view!
    pLay = CALayer()
    pLay.frame = myView.bounds
    pLay.bounds = pLay.frame
    pLay.delegate = self
    myView.layer.addSublayer(pLay)
    pLay.setNeedsDisplay()
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
    let start = touch.location(in: myView)
    print("START: X: \(start.x) Y: \(start.y)")
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
    let end = touch.location(in: myView)
    print("END: X: \(end.x) Y: \(end.y)")
    pLay.setNeedsDisplay()
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    touch = touches.first
    prevLoc = touch.previousLocation(in: myView)
    loc = touch.location(in: myView)
    if ((loc.x != prevLoc.x) && (loc.y != prevLoc.y)) {
        print("MOVED: prev: \(prevLoc.x), \(prevLoc.y) loc: \(loc.x), \(loc.y)")
        pLay.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

func draw(_ layer: CALayer, in con: CGContext) {
    guard let t = touch else {
        return
    }

    if (img != nil) {
        con.draw(img, in: layer.bounds)
    }

    if t.type == .stylus {
        lineWidth = 2
        con.setStrokeColor(drawColor.cgColor)
    }

    con.setLineWidth(lineWidth)
    con.setLineCap(.round)

    con.move(to: CGPoint(x: prevLoc.x, y: prevLoc.y))
    con.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: loc.x, y: loc.y))
    con.strokePath()
    img = con.makeImage()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This was a case of "if it ain't broke don't fix it".  I had this code working fine using an ImageView but felt it was inefficient so tried to implement in the Layer.   The way I was trying to save state and then restore in a Layer basically wasn't appropriate.  The main problem here was calling `con.draw(img, in: layer.bounds)` while in `draw` which created the mirrored drawing, but there were enough other issues (like the different coordinate origin point) that had me go back to my original implementation.